# Non-English in-text citation

Tags: bibtex, lyx, languages

I have changed the language setting in my lyx document to Danish but my in-text citations still read e.g. (`Jones and Jones, 2013`) and not (`Jones og Jones, 2013`) which would be the Danish equivalent.

Is it possible to change this? Alternatively to change `and` to `&`?

Comment: What package do you use to create the bibliography? What style do you use? You can modify the `.bst` file (presuming you use some BibTeX package). You could also use `biblatex`.

Comment: Rasmus, if you are going to cross-post (post the same question in more than one place), please always state where you posted on all your posts: http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=23789&p=80958#p80958

Answer (score 5):

I suppose that you are using package `natbib`. Then try in the preamble of your document:

```
\renewcommand\betweenauthors{og}
\providecommand\harvardand{}
\renewcommand\harvardand{og}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use a package relying on `.bst` styles, you will have to manually edit the `.bst` files yourself.

If you, for example use `\bibliographystyle{plain}`, we need to modify `plain.bst` (you can find the styles in `texmf/bibtex/bst`), the relevant function is `FUNCTION {format.names}`

```
FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 's :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr "{ff~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=
      nameptr #1 >
    { namesleft #1 >
        { ", " * t * }
        { numnames #2 >
        { "," * }
        'skip$
          if$
          t "others" =
        { " et~al." * }% change this if you like
        { " og " * t * }% <----- change this from " and " to " og "
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
    't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
}
```

Save this file under a different name, say `plaindan.bst`, where LaTeX can find it and change the line `\bibliographystyle{plain}` to `\bibliographystyle{plaindan}`.

Comment: Thanks. I am using "plainnat". Is it possible to do the same trick here? Somehow I couldn't find a bst file called "plainnat".I would really appreciate the author-year citation style

Comment: Of course you can use this solution for `plainnat` as well, you will find the file in `texmf/bibtex/natbib/plainnat.bst` the relevant function is located in line 216 (in my version of the file). But if Herbert's solution works for you, you should really be using that one.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found a solution using the provided example  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well, in my case Herbert and moewe's suggestions didn't help. I had to change the `FUNCTION {format.lab.names}`

```
%                       There are three apalike cases: one person (Jones),
%                       two (Jones and de~Bruijn), and more (Jones et~al.).
%                       This function is much like format.crossref.editors.
%
FUNCTION {format.lab.names}
{ 's :=
  s #1 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$
  s num.names$ duplicate$
  #2 >
    { pop$ " et~al." * }
    { #2 <
        'skip$
        { s #2 "{ff }{vv }{ll}{ jj}" format.name$ "others" =
            { " et~al." * }
            { " and " * s #2 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ * } <-- Change here
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
```